# Debugging typescript generics

Tags: typescript

For example I have some tipes like below (this typeings taken from react-redux library). Please, don't try to deep dive in all this, my question relates not to these exact types.

Question is, does typescript provides some means to debug generics like this? I mean, if I use `connect` function with some specific types, some exact path will be choosen by TypeScript compiler, and some resulting type will be generated. Can I debug compilation process to see how compiler process typings step by step?

I know that I can do something like this

```
type a = Match<type1, type2>
```

And then see what type `a` will be. But may be some easier method exist? Espesially with so complicated types as below?

```
export const connect: Connect;

export interface Connect {
    // tslint:disable:no-unnecessary-generics
    (): InferableComponentEnhancer<DispatchProp>;

    <TStateProps = {}, no_dispatch = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TStateProps & DispatchProp, TOwnProps>;

    <no_state = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: null | undefined,
        mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsNonObject<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;

    <no_state = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: null | undefined,
        mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<
        ResolveThunks<TDispatchProps>,
        TOwnProps
    >;

    <TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>,
        mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsNonObject<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TStateProps & TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;

    <TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>,
        mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<
       TStateProps & ResolveThunks<TDispatchProps>,
       TOwnProps
    >;

    <TStateProps = {}, no_dispatch = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps = {}, State = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>,
        mapDispatchToProps: null | undefined,
        mergeProps: MergeProps<TStateProps, undefined, TOwnProps, TMergedProps>,
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TMergedProps, TOwnProps>;

    <no_state = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: null | undefined,
        mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
        mergeProps: MergeProps<undefined, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps, TMergedProps>,
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TMergedProps, TOwnProps>;

    <no_state = {}, no_dispatch = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: null | undefined,
        mapDispatchToProps: null | undefined,
        mergeProps: MergeProps<undefined, undefined, TOwnProps, TMergedProps>,
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TMergedProps, TOwnProps>;

    <TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps = {}, State = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>,
        mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
        mergeProps: MergeProps<TStateProps, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps, TMergedProps>,
        options?: Options<State, TStateProps, TOwnProps, TMergedProps>
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TMergedProps, TOwnProps>;

    <TStateProps = {}, no_dispatch = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>,
        mapDispatchToProps: null | undefined,
        mergeProps: null | undefined,
        options: Options<State, TStateProps, TOwnProps>
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<DispatchProp & TStateProps, TOwnProps>;
}

export type InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TInjectedProps, TNeedsProps> =
    <C extends ComponentType<Matching<TInjectedProps, GetProps<C>>>>(
        component: C
    ) => ConnectedComponentClass<C, Omit<GetProps<C>, keyof Shared<TInjectedProps, GetProps<C>>> & TNeedsProps>;

export type Matching<InjectedProps, DecorationTargetProps> = {
    [P in keyof DecorationTargetProps]: P extends keyof InjectedProps
        ? InjectedProps[P] extends DecorationTargetProps[P]
            ? DecorationTargetProps[P]
            : InjectedProps[P]
        : DecorationTargetProps[P];
};

export type InferThunkActionCreatorType<TActionCreator extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    TActionCreator extends (...args: infer TParams) => (...args: any[]) => infer TReturn
        ? (...args: TParams) => TReturn
        : TActionCreator;

export type HandleThunkActionCreator<TActionCreator> =
    TActionCreator extends (...args: any[]) => any
        ? InferThunkActionCreatorType<TActionCreator>
        : TActionCreator;

export type ResolveThunks<TDispatchProps> =
    TDispatchProps extends { [key: string]: any }
        ? {
            [C in keyof TDispatchProps]: HandleThunkActionCreator<TDispatchProps[C]>
        }
        : TDispatchProps;
```

Sorry, not all types shown, as there were alot of types present

Comment: I am wondering the same but didn't heard about `Match` and looks like it is not in the TypeScript globals. Can you tell me where you picked it up ?